# How do I apply the filter on Temp table and store the result into same Temp table after removing old data from same temp table

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

```
ALTER PROCEDURE InLiceneseAdmRoute 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@Region nvarchar(500)=NULL,
@Country nvarchar(500)=NULL
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    IF @Region IS NOT NULL AND @Region!=''
    BEGIN

        IF EXISTS(SELECT [name] FROM tempdb.sys.tables WHERE [name] like '#TempAdmRoute%') 
        BEGIN
            DROP TABLE #TempAdmRoute
        END

        CREATE TABLE #TempAdmRoute(
                Country nvarchar(250),
                API1 nvarchar(250),
                API2 nvarchar(250),
                API3 nvarchar(250),
                AdmRoute nvarchar(250))

        INSERT INTO #TempAdmRoute(Country,API1,API2,API3,AdmRoute)
        SELECT Country,API1,API2,API3,AdmRoute
        FROM dbo.Product
        WHERE 
        AdmRoute is not null and AdmRoute !='' and 
        ScrapePipeline ='S' and 
        Region in (SELECT items FROM [dbo].[Split] (@Region, ',')) and
        IsActive = 1


        IF @Country IS NOT NULL AND @Country !='' 
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #TempAdmRoute
            SELECT Country,API1,API2,API3,AdmRoute 
            FROM #TempAdmRoute
            WHERE Country =@Country

            IF @API1IS NOT NULL AND @API1!='' 
            BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #TempAdmRoute
            SELECT Country,API1,API2,API3,AdmRoute 
            FROM #TempAdmRoute
            WHERE API1=@API1
            END
        END

            select * from #TempAdmRoute

    END 
END
GO
```

I have used above code to retrieve data from 10,00,000 reocrds so I have used the temp table.is it possible to retrieve the records from #TempAdmRoute and before storing the records into #TempAdmRoute clear all the previous records ?

Comment: Have you tried `DELETE #TempAdmRoute` before your `INSERT` statements?

Comment: Where did you declare @API1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied the filter on **#TempInLiceneseAPI** table and remove the records from table that doesn't matches with the search criteria

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT [name] FROM tempdb.sys.tables WHERE [name] like '#TempInLiceneseAPI%') 
        BEGIN
            DROP TABLE #TempInLiceneseAPI
        END

        CREATE TABLE #TempInLiceneseAPI(
                Country nvarchar(500),
                API1 nvarchar(250),
                API2 nvarchar(250),
                API3 nvarchar(250))

        INSERT INTO #TempInLiceneseAPI(Country,API1,API2,API3)
        SELECT Country,API1,API2,API3
        FROM dbo.Product
        WHERE 
        API1 is not null and 
        API1 !='' and 
        ScrapePipeline ='S' and
        Region in (SELECT items FROM [dbo].[Split] (@Region, ',')) and
        IsActive =1

        IF @Country IS NOT NULL AND @Country !='' 
        BEGIN
            DELETE FROM #TempInLiceneseAPI
            WHERE Country NOT IN(SELECT items FROM [dbo].[Split] (@Country, ','))
        END

        IF @API1 IS NOT NULL AND @API1 !='' AND @API1 !='0'
        BEGIN
            DELETE FROM #TempInLiceneseAPI WHERE API1 !=@API1 OR API1 IS NULL

            IF @API2 IS NOT NULL AND @API2 !='' AND @API2 !='0'
            BEGIN
                DELETE FROM #TempInLiceneseAPI WHERE API2 !=@API2 OR API2 IS NULL

                IF @API3 IS NOT NULL AND @API3 !='' AND @API3 !='0'
                BEGIN
                    DELETE FROM #TempInLiceneseAPI WHERE API3 !=@API3 OR API3 IS NULL
                END
            END
        END
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear to me where `@API1` comes from.  You aren't defining it within the stored procedure.

Rather than copy selected records from the table back into itself, you could delete all the records that you -don't- want in the table.  That would probably make for the simplest code.

In fact, if you know `@API1` before you copy the records, you could add an additional filter to your INSERT to `#TempAdmRoute`.

Or, since (from appearances) you ultimately return the contents of `#TempAdmRoute`, you could filter the query where you return the contents of `#TempAdmRoute`.

But, if none of that will work, you could copy the contents of `#TempAdmRoute` into a table variable or a second temporary table, delete the contents of `#TempAdmRoute`, and then insert into `#TempAdmRoute` from your table variable or second temporary table.

```
    IF @Country IS NOT NULL AND @Country !='' 
    BEGIN

       CREATE @SecondTempAdmRoute TABLE
       (
            Country nvarchar(250),
            API1 nvarchar(250),
            API2 nvarchar(250),
            API3 nvarchar(250),
            AdmRoute nvarchar(250)
       )

       INSERT INTO @SecondTempAdmRoute
       SELECT * FROM #TempAdmRoute

       DELETE FROM #TempAdmRoute

       INSERT INTO #TempAdmRoute
       SELECT Country,API1,API2,API3,AdmRoute 
       FROM @SecondTempAdmRoute
       WHERE Country =@Country

       IF @API1 IS NOT NULL AND @API1!='' 
       BEGIN
          INSERT INTO #TempAdmRoute
           SELECT Country,API1,API2,API3,AdmRoute 
           FROM @SecondTempAdmRoute
          WHERE API1=@API1
       END
    END
```

It isn't possible to delete the contents of a table and then query the contents you just deleted.  These are separate steps and once the records are deleted, they are deleted.